# Fedora virtual terminal won't scroll after switch

Tags: linux, terminal, console

I recently installed Fedora 12 for some Linux testing. When I switch between virtual terminals (CTRL-f1 Ctrl-f2) I can no longer scroll back in the VT I left and came back to. Any new data created will be scrollable, but i can never get back to before the switch. I'm sure this used to work (several years ago). Was this introduced as a security feature to prevent left over data on VTs from being seen by the wrong eyes? If so, is there a way to get the old functionality back?

Answer (score 2):

scrollback is stored in video RAM, when you switch VTs the origin point moves back to the start of the VRAM and your buffer is erased. this is how it has always been, as far as I know.